# Retrieving Registry nodes for HKLM

Tags: vb.net, windows

I am using the below code to retrieve nodes and values. It is taking 20 mins to retrieve the nodes and values of HKLM.

I'm expecting to reduce the retrieving time

`Getting nodes`

```
    Private Function f_GetSubkeys(ByVal WindowsRegistryKey As RegistryKey) As Integer
            For Each subkeyName As String In WindowsRegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames
                Try
                    count = count + 1
                    Dim vSubKey As RegistryKey = WindowsRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(subkeyName)
                    If (vSubKey Is Nothing) Then
                        Continue For
                    End If
                    If f_ToGetRegistryData(vSubKey) <> 0 Then Return -1
                    If f_getsubkeys(vSubKey) <> 0 Then Return -1
                Catch ex As SecurityException
                    sExceptionHandling.Append(WindowsRegistryKey.Name & "\" & subkeyName & "," & ex.Message & vbNewLine)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                    Return -1
                End Try
            Next
            Return 0
End Function
'To get values of registry data

Public Function f_ToGetRegistryData(ByVal regSubKey As RegistryKey) As Integer
        Try
            Dim SettingValue As String = ""
            Dim type As String = ""
            Dim KeyNames As New List(Of String)
            KeyNames = regSubKey.GetValueNames.ToList

            'To get the the registry values(Name, Type & data)
            For Each SettingName In KeyNames
                Dim SettingType = regSubKey.GetValueKind(SettingName)
                If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.Binary Then
                    type = "REG_BINARY"
                    Dim value = regSubKey.GetValue(SettingName)
                    SettingValue = BitConverter.ToString(value)
                ElseIf SettingType = RegistryValueKind.MultiString Then
                    type = "REG_MULTI_SZ"
                    Dim Data As String() = regSubKey.GetValue(SettingName)
                    SettingValue = (String.Join(" ", Data))
                    SettingValue = SettingValue.Replace(",", " ")
                ElseIf SettingType = RegistryValueKind.None Then
                    type = "REG_NONE"
                    Dim value = regSubKey.GetValue(SettingName)
                    SettingValue = BitConverter.ToString(value)
                ElseIf SettingType = RegistryValueKind.Unknown Then
                    'type = "UNKNOWN TYPE"
                    'SettingValue = "UNKNOWN DATA"
                    Dim proc As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                    Dim pr As Process
                    proc.CreateNoWindow = True
                    proc.UseShellExecute = False
                    proc.RedirectStandardInput = True
                    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                    pr = Process.Start(proc)
                    Dim paths = regSubKey.ToString
                    Dim value = SettingName.ToString
                    Dim fullpath = "Reg Query " & Chr(34) & paths & Chr(34) & " /v " & Chr(34) & value & Chr(34)
                    pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(fullpath)
                    pr.StandardInput.Close()
                    Dim writer As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
                    Dim arr As String() = pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(vbLf))
                    Dim len As Integer = arr.Length
                    Dim regval = arr(6)
                    regval = RTrim(LTrim(regval))
                    Dim regValSplit = regval.Split("    ")
                    SettingName = value
                    type = regValSplit(regValSplit.Length - 5).ToString
                    Dim Setting = regValSplit(regValSplit.Length - 1).ToString
                    SettingValue = Setting.Replace(vbCr, "")
                    Dim output As String = writer.ToString()
                    pr.StandardOutput.Close()
                Else
                    SettingValue = regSubKey.GetValue(SettingName).ToString

                    If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.ExpandString Then
                        SettingValue = SettingValue.Replace(",", " ")
                        type = "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
                    End If

                    If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.DWord Then
                        type = "REG_DWORD"
                    End If

                    If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.QWord Then
                        type = "REG_QWORD"
                        If SettingValue = "System.Byte[]" Then
                            SettingValue = " "
                        End If
                    End If

                    If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.String Then
                        SettingValue = SettingValue.Replace(",", " ")
                        type = "REG_SZ"
                    End If
                End If
                f_AppendData(regSubKey.Name, SettingName, type, SettingValue)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Return -1
        End Try
        Return 0
    End Function
```